# Is there any alternative to "Float" for a flex container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Recently I noted that `float: right/left` doesn't work on a child element when the parent container has `display: flex`. I want some of the child elements to be pushed towards the right just as we do with `float: right`.

```css
.bodycontainer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #666633;
  padding: 10px 0;

}
.bodycontainer2 {
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #666633;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: justify;
}

.floating_right {
  float: right;
}
.floating_left {
  float: left;
}
.make_inline_block {
  display: inline-block;
}
.make_block {
  display: block;
}
.make_inline {
  display: inline;
}
.make_margin_top {
  margin-top: 10px; 
}
.vertical_align {
  vertical-align: middle;  
}
.make_flex_align_vertical {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
/* My framework finishes */
```

```html
<div class="bodycontainer">
  <div class="bodycontainer2">
    <div class="make_margin make_flex_align_vertical">
      <span class="floating_left"> An Interview </span>
      <audio controls class="floating_right">
        <source src="audio/best.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
      </audio> 
      <a class="buy_button floating_right" href="http://www.soundcloud.html">Buy Now</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zmwb9v6m/).

I want `audio` and `buy now` to float right and the text `An Interview` to float left.

Is there any alternative to Float for a flex container?

Comment: Yes, [**floats are ignored in a flex formatting context**](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/CR-css-flexbox-1-20160301/#flex-containers). The flex alternative is [**auto margins**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes...it's just a matter of adjusting margins like so:

```css
.child {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #000;
  margin: 5px;
}
.parent {
  display: flex;
}
.child:first-of-type {
  margin-right: auto; /* everything after me gets pushed to the right end*/
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.floating_left {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```css
.bodycontainer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #666633;
  padding: 10px 0;

}
.bodycontainer2 {
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #666633;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: justify;
}

.floating_right {
  float: right;
}
.floating_left {
  flex: 1;
}
.make_inline_block {
  display: inline-block;
}
.make_block {
  display: block;
}
.make_inline {
  display: inline;
}
.make_margin_top {
  margin-top: 10px; 
}
.vertical_align {
  vertical-align: middle;  
}
.make_flex_align_vertical {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
/* My framework finishes */
```

```html
<div class="bodycontainer">
  <div class="bodycontainer2">
    <div class="make_margin make_flex_align_vertical">
      <span class="floating_left"> An Interview </span>
      <audio controls class="floating_right">
        <source src="audio/best.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
      </audio> 
      <a class="buy_button floating_right" href="http://www.soundcloud.html">Buy Now</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```